# Error in LineEdit when show parsing value as string

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, xml, pyqt

I m trying to make QGIS plugin to open xml, parse it and then show value i parse from xml to line edit, i use this code :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_testparse import Ui_testparse
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree
# create the dialog for zoom to point


class testparseDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_testparse()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        opendata = self.ui.btnCari
        QtCore.QObject.connect(opendata, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.openxml)



    def openxml(self, event=None):

        #open dialog
        openfile = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '*.xml')

        self.ui.lineLokasi.setText(openfile)

        #call XML data
        self.isiData(openfile)

    def isiData(self, nmsatu):
        #open teks with read mode
        openteks = open(nmsatu, 'r').read()

        self.ui.textXml.setText(openteks)

        #Parse XML from Above
        self.parsenow(openteks)

    def parsenow(self, parse):
        element = ETree.fromstring(parse)
        xml_obj = ETree.ElementTree(element)
        for title_obj in xml_obj.findall('.//{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}dateStamp/'
             '{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco}Date'):
                #print element
                list1 = [element]
                Str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in list1)
        self.ui.lineSkala.setText(Str1)
```

And the xml file i parse have a format like this:

```
<gmd:dateStamp>
      <gco:Date>2013-12-12</gco:Date>
   </gmd:dateStamp>
   <gmd:metadataStandardName>
      <gco:CharacterString>ISO 19115</gco:CharacterString>
   </gmd:metadataStandardName>
   <gmd:metadataStandardVersion>
      <gco:CharacterString>ISO19115:2003</gco:CharacterString>
   </gmd:metadataStandardVersion>
```

I want to show Date Value (2013-12-12) inside `<gco:Date>2013-12-12</gco:Date>` to lineEdit but instead of show date (2013-12-12) it show like some random code like this :

```
<Element '{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}MD_Metadata' at 0xd3e3c30>
```

Can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

It is a pure Python problem and you really need to understand how ElementTree works:

In your XML file,`gmd` and `gco` are namespaces shortcuts for something  that must be defined in the XML file (you cannot use them directly with ElementTree).

Example of definitions of the namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gmd xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">
   <gmd:dateStamp>
       <gco:Date>2013-12-12</gco:Date>
    </gmd:dateStamp>
 </gmd>
```

To illustrate the problem, I'll use the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module,  which allows to set the namespace in the xpath query:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('file.xml')
print tree.xpath(".//gmd:dateStamp/*/text()",namespaces={'gmd':"http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"})
['2013-12-12']
```

With ElementTree, you must specify the namespaces (and not the shorcuts) in the query:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
date = tree.find(".//{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}dateStamp/{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco}Date")
print date.text
2013-12-12
```

More simply, to illustrate the ElementTree, module, I'll use it for parsing a **.qml** file:

The layers in a qml files:

[image]

```
attributes = tree.find( './/projectlayers/maplayer')
print attributes
{'maximumScale': '1e+08', 'hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag': '0', 'type': 'raster', 'minimumScale': '0'}
 for elem in tree.findall('.//projectlayers/maplayer/'):
      # attributes type, name, source
      print("type :"),elem.attrib["type"]
      print("name :"), elem.find('layername').text
      print("source : "), elem.find('datasource').text

  type : raster
  name : test_raster
  source : /Users/Shared/test.tif

  type : vector
  name: test_shape
  source : /Users/Shared/test.shp
```